# Backoffice Itemtype Filtering

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I have an item called InoLocation , it has an enumtype called 'InoLocationType'.
This enumtype contains 3 value : COUNTRY, CITY, COUNTY.
There are impexes which imports cities and counties to this itemtype.
On items.xml, i created an attribute called 'cities', its type is InoLocation.

On default, 'cities' returns all enum types. 
I want to filter these enums, just show CITY type on backoffice.

Is it possible?

```
<enumtypes>
    <enumtype code="InoLocationType" >
        <value code="COUNTRY"></value>
        <value code="CITY"></value>
        <value code="COUNTY"></value>
    </enumtype>
</enumtypes>

<itemtypes>
    <itemtype generate="true"
              code="InoLocation"
              jaloclass="com.inomera.hybris.custom.location.jalo.InoLocation"
              extends="GenericItem"
              autocreate="true">
        <deployment table="ino_location" typecode="11115"/>

        <attributes>

            <attribute qualifier="code" type="java.lang.String">
                <description>City's Plate Code</description>
                <modifiers initial="true"/>
                <persistence type="property"/>
            </attribute>

            <attribute qualifier="name" type="java.lang.String">
                <description>Location Name</description>
                <modifiers initial="true"/>
                <persistence type="property"/>
            </attribute>

            <attribute qualifier="parent" type="InoLocation">
                <description>Selected location's parent location</description>
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true"/>
                <persistence type="property"/>
            </attribute>

            <attribute qualifier="type" type="InoLocationType">
                <description>Location Type</description>
                <modifiers initial="true"/>
                <persistence type="property"/>
            </attribute>


        </attributes>

    </itemtype>
</itemtypes>
```

[Cities label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoomV.jpg) , 
[Cities label opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW8qZ.jpg)

One more thing,

These screens are from backoffice, they return as models, i want them return with their 'name' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below snippet to make only "CITY" available in backoffice.

```
<attribute qualifier="type" type="InoLocationType">
   <description>Location Type</description>
   <defaultvalue>em().getEnumerationValue("InoLocationType", "CITY")</defaultvalue>
   <modifiers optional="false" read="true" write="false"/>
    <persistence type="property"/>
</attribute>
```

This would enable the default value of the attribute type as "CITY" and the attribute is present as a non-changeable attribute.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply but it didn't work. The area of city attribute still returns all the adress values.    https://imgur.com/MiDlGzg  https://imgur.com/ieXX5nm

Comment: just confirming, did you do 'ant clean updatesystem'?

Answer (score 0):

Think about the `availableValuesProvider` editor-parameter:

```
<wz:property qualifier="cities">
    <wz:editor-parameter>
         <wz:name>availableValuesProvider</wz:name>
         <wz:value>onlyWhatIWantToDisplayProvider</wz:value>
     </wz:editor-parameter>
</wz:property>
```

`onlyWhatIWantToDisplayProvider` is an implementation of `ReferenceEditorSearchFacade` that you have to declare as a spring bean.